# JMeter MultiUser and single user Auto Login Script

Tags: jmeter

How to check Multiuser and single user Autologin Load test in my website..

I have studied the tutorial but I don't understand it. Below are the steps that I follow..

```
Test->Add->Theard Group ->Recording Controller
Test->Add->Config Element->HTTP Request Default
Test->Add->Config Element->HttpCookie Manager
Workbench->Add->NonTestElement->Http(s)Test Script Recorder
```

I set Httpdomain name->adda52.org, http sampler settings and add exclude patterns in Step 4 and then start. After that I set the browser setting proxy server and run login our site..

Everything is going fine.

Then I add view result and see that the result of each request is fine. Then I pass a dynamic session value by using the following steps:

under Recording controller->login page->add->Post Processer->Regular expression extractor add under reference

name                 salt (This is my session id)
Regular Expression         name="salt" value="(.*?)" />
Match No                    1
Default value =  session Not found

and then set this session value is my after login page like this : ${salt} and run our script session value is showing on my post data.

My question is

```
Is my script is correct? if yes then
    After login I cannot see on profile page in Response data in View Result trees they are showng blank page ?
How can I make my script to auto login on multiple users and single user?
How can I check load on my site and where
```

please provide me step and how to check.?

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps carefully:

1. List item

   ```
      test plan->Add->Thread(user)->Thread group
      thread group->Add->config element->HTTP Request Defaults
      thread group->logic controller->recording controller
   ```

   **Workspace->Add->non-test element->http test script recorder**
2. start your plan & record it.after successful creating of test plan do the following steps: add the csv data set config in your test plan 
    **Thread group->add->config element->csv data set config**
3. in csv data set config file give the parameter values like :  in filename:-**give your csv file path & in variable name pass the variable as:username,password**
4. in your test plan check the login file in that file change the static values username as "${username}" & password "${password}"
5. pass the different values in csv file & before start the test plan change the number of thread you want run

Comment: Hi Thanks For your replay.. But one thing ..1. when I am Follow these step it is allow for single user login or multiple user auto login or  both of them ..2.In csv FILE which type of data store or autometic save data when i am run the script...?

Comment: you needs to be give values from the csv file for multiuser login before that do the parameterization as i worte in your test plan replace your username with ${username} & password with ${password} & give the different values in csv file

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replay..but one thing on my site my password is generate Random password..like: password+session..in this case how to manage our password..my site is https://www.adda52.org,or www.adda52.com  and user name : rajan_srivastava and pass:123456789

Comment: Hi,When I am using single Thread then it's not show on database login ,but in Jmeter it's show login and  when I am Using 5 or 8 thread then it's show 2 to 3 times login in database..can you plz tell me what is the problem...?my database value is store sessions based on sessionid. and this session store in DB...

Comment: Please give me your email id, I will send you test plan which i have created

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Reply..My Email ID is--rajancs007@gmail.com

Comment: Hi,
 Thanks For Your Replay.
 But one thing I can not understand. when i register user through JMeter,
 Users record are not store in database? in this case what can i do.please help me.